# Need some fix in live action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little code that make a div popup in a click on a button.
What im trying to do is when i click on the button it pop up a new div + a background div with opacity- Thats work fine. But im trying to do not just when i click the close button it will hide both div, also when i click on the background div it will hide them.
when i click on the button its hide both.
but when i click on the background div it is just hide the background and keep the popup.
here is the code:

```
function closebox() 
{
    var boxID = $(this).attr("box_id");

    $("#opacback").animate( { "opacity": "0" }, 500, function()
    {
        $('#inside_image'+boxID)
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('animated flipOutX')
            .fadeOut('slow');  
        $("#opacback").hide(); 
    });    
}
```

as I said, when i click on the background it is just remove the opacity of the background div but keep the popup. when i click on the close button it do both.
how this is possible since both using the same function?

this is the background div calling :

```
$('#opacback').live('click', closebox);
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle

Comment: 'live' is depreciated. Use 'on'.

Comment: That's probably because the bg div doesn't have a box id

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, you could use an existing plugin that does this, like jquery colorbox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: Obligatory: have you stepped through this through the debugger to see if the same code ends up executed when you click the button and the background?

Comment: @Dom, `.live()` isn't just deprecated, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: It doesn't work with on as well, and the code isnt break because when i click on the original close button it is close and it using the same function. when i click on the background div it is just drop the opacity and hide him but keep the popup .

Comment: I would take a guess your `#obacback` does not have the correct value in the attribute `box_id`, like what your close button does. Although it's hard to tell with out seeing the rest of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) will refer to different things depending on what is clicked.

If one or more of your elements that is being clicked doesn't have the `box_id` attribute, your script will break.

If you post your HTML, someone can probably provide a more specific answer.

Comment: thanks as i see it now.. thats realy was the problem.. but now i have another problem, I have 4 boxes..(mean 4 different numbers for the boxID) and the background div can provide just one number. How can i make it work ?

Comment: You really need to include your html and ideally create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it easier to see what is going on to the folks here.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle but i got some problem and somehow it doesnt work as it works on my site.. I cant provide my own html cuz its on a full site im building. the problem now is that my bg div has one number like box_id="1" and i need to change it for each of the popups. there is anyway to do it without creat 4 different bg divs ?

Comment: At a *very* rough guess - either set the `box_id` attribute of the background when you are showing it or find the div (box?) that is currently visible using a selector specific to the visible box.

Comment: sorry for the stupid questions im kinda new of this.. How do i set the attr ? Im thinking instead of searching the attr.. il just set them everytime for the exact value.. If its like .attr('box_id' , '1'); its doesnt work

Comment: That works for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3gvZ/)